# How to Set Authorization HTTP Header with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'm using oauth in an API library and the API requires that the Authorization header be explicitly set for each request.

I'm familiar with the setRequestHeader method, using it like:

```
this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

However, I'm not sure how to properly set the Authorization header, since it has so many parameters. An example of what the header needs to look like is:

```
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_consumer_key="consumer",oauth_token="foo",oauth_timestamp="timestamp",oauth_nonce="ononce",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_signature="osig"
```

How do I properly set the Authorization header in this format using setRequestHeader? Thanks!

Comment: which javascript library are you using?

Comment: not using any library... vanilla javascript in appcelerator's titanium mobile to build an iPad app.

Comment: here is the Titanium api for request headers http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.setRequestHeader-method.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the OAuth javascript library.  It's setup to build those signed OAuth headers for you...

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/